# Magento 2.0 How to redirect in observer

Tags: php, magento2

I have declared observer for **controller_action_postdispatch** event.
In excecute method I check if customer is logged in. If not he should be redirected to login page.

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
  # check if user is logged in
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $customerSession = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

  if(!$customerSession->isLoggedIn())
  {
    $request = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');

    if(strpos($request->getPathInfo(), '/customer/account/') !== 0)
    {
       # redirect to /customer/account/login
    }
  }
}
```

How can I redirect client to another URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This's how it can be done:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
  # check if user is logged in
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

  if(!$customerSession->isLoggedIn())
  {
    $request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');
    //get instance for URL interface
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface */
    $urlInterface = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
    // URL to redirect to
    $url = $urlInterface->getUrl('customer/account/login');

    if(strpos($request->getPathInfo(), '/customer/account/') !== 0)
    {
        # redirect to /customer/account/login
        $observer->getControllerAction()
         ->getResponse()
         ->setRedirect($url);
    }
  }
}
```

that's it. Now it'll redirect to customer login page. I've tested this with event `controller_action_predispatch`

Comment: Oh I did not know I could do that - :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code for redirecting to other page from phtml page

```
 # check if user is logged in
      $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
      $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

      if(!$customerSession->isLoggedIn())
      {
        $request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');
        //get instance for URL interface
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface */
        $urlInterface = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
        // URL to redirect to
        $url = $urlInterface->getUrl('customer/account/login');

        if(strpos($request->getPathInfo(), '/customer/account/') !== 0)
        {
            # redirect to /customer/account/login

             header('Location:'.$url );die();

        }
      }
```